# adding global values on to window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have an application, so inside the code I am checking window.name property, So when i open the tab and hit the application URL Before my applications loads i wan't to run this code in chrome console. So that application will have it

```
window.name = "Test"
```

Is there any way to achieve this on chrome console, i tried adding this but when i add meanwhile the application gets loaded and window.name comes as undefined. After setting it if i refresh then again application loads and window.name gets removed.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use the Debugger to set a breakpoint before the JS tries to test the value, then refresh the page to trigger the breakpoint. Then switch to the console, run the extra code, then continue from the breakpoint.